# Facebook Messenger app/notifications on Linux 2019?

Tags: xubuntu, xfce, notification, mail, facebook

Searching only brings up old results from around 2013 or 2014. How is the state of things for Facebook notifications on Linux? Is there an app that notifies me when new messages arrive? Any kind of notification is welcomed, if not sound at least a flashing light on the panel bar, anything. (Xubuntu 16.04.3 here)

Comment: FYI: Flavors only have three years support; thus all 16.04 LTS flavors are EOL with exception of Ubuntu-Kylin (*two extra years provided by Canonical*) You can note this in https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2018/03/03/ubuntu-16-04-4-lts-released/ which also shows 2018-March-1st 16.04.4 came out (it's now 16.04.6) highlighting you are behind on upgrades or have your release details incorrect; possibly you installed 16.04.3.  I would suggest moving to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (server with no desktop, or Unity 7 desktop, even Kylin) or upgrade to Xubuntu 18.04 LTS.  Use `ubuntu-support-status` to confirm

Comment: You need to upgrade your installation as you're using an EOL version of Xubuntu.  Either moving to the 18.04 LTS or the 19.10 interim release would be advisable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an app called [Caprine](https://github.com/sindresorhus/caprine) which can be used as Facebook  messenger. The software offers `.deb`, `.snap`, and `.Appimage` packages to make it easy to install.
According to their github page

> **Desktop notifications**
>
> Desktop notifications can be turned on in Preferences.